# AEM Touch-Optimized UI not found

Tags: adobe, aem, experience-manager

I'm new in AEM. I've encountered an error page,right after I have login as admin.

Not Found

Cannot serve request to /projects.html in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

Thanks for the help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZhtM.jpg)

Comment: Try to start your instance with start.bat from crx-quickstart/bin folder...Don't  start your instance from quickstart jar. Most of the time it creates problem like this and jsp rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you able to see any AEM page?  For example are you able to navigate to localhost:4502/crx/de   ?
2. This may be your antivirus / firewall blocking it, have you tried switching them off temporarily and trying?